# Return 2 tables from a store procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, stored-procedures

I have a SP where I create 2 temporary tables, fill them with data, and I need to return them so I can show them in my .net application.

In .net I make the following to call the SP:

```
Dim sentencias As MySqlCommand
Dim tabla As DataTable = New DataTable
sentencias = New MySqlCommand(sp, Me.getcon())
sentencias.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
sentencias.Parameters.Add("@Param", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = value
sentencias.CommandTimeout = 600000
Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
myReader = sentencias.ExecuteReader()
tabla.Load(myReader)
datagrid.DataSource = tabla
myReader.Close()
```

How can I call the SP and return both tables?

This SP is very cpu & i/o intensive, since it has 2 cursors reading enormous tables (it is expected to last 15 minutes). There is no way I can split the sp in order to return 1 table each.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to return just one result set...if both results have the same number of columns you could use `UNION`

Comment: both tables are way different. IIRC in SQL server this can be achieved with no issues am I right?

Comment: Yes Vallo...if you execute the sp directly on the sql server you can see the results from both tables....but on the .Net app it only takes the last result set....cheers :)